# Return individual values from linkedHashMap in Mule

Tags: mule, linkedhashmap

I have an output from a webservice in Mule that returns a linkedHashMap and I need to get the individual values to be dynamically inserted into a template. The template is used to send email through the SMTP connector. I can get all values using MEL #[payload], but I can't get them one by one. I've tried #[payload.get(0)], #[payload[0]] but they all return null.

The Mule XML looks like this:

```
<flow name="MW_Flow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\....\1" connector-    ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" pollingFrequency="60000"/>
    <ws:consumer config-ref="File_Read_WS" operation="all3" doc:name="FileRead DBWriter WS"/>
    <dw:transform-message metadata:id="6ee92ba8-9f67-40d6-bfa3-3e237da20822" doc:name="Transform Message">

<foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <parse-template location="C:\.....\Templates\Mail.txt" metadata:id="b7d894eb-465b-47f7-a542-b49fc4fb53d9" doc:name="Parse Template"/>
        <logger message="2: #[message.exception] #[message.dataType] #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```

The template (plain text file) looks a bit like this:

Hello [name].
This is email from [name2]. The following event [event].....

All I get are null values except when using #[payload] which returns the whole row (4 values).

Any help greatly appreciated!
/Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your payload is a `Map` then payload.get(0) or payload[0] will behave as if you are trying to get a value from map with 0 as key, which I guess doesn't exist in your map.

Try accessing it with name - `#[payload.name]` or `#[payload.name2]` or `#[payload[name]]`

Comment: I tried those but they didn't work, but using the "." made me try another way which actually worked, #[payload.column_name] Quite obvious in retrospect... Anyways, thx for your quick response!

Comment: Glad it worked!  Do you mean #[payload.column_name] worked? If yes, then that's what I had mentioned in answer #[payload.name], I assumed you have name key in map because you was using that in template :).

Comment: Yes, #[payload.column_name] worked! I didn't realize that at first because the actual name of my column wasn't name, I just wrote it here to make it simpler to understand :|